# Middleman server not compiling coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript, middleman

I've used Middleman in the past to work on static projects, and have used CoffeeScript in those projects. In this instance it does not seem to be working. I was under the impression that CoffeeScript compilation should work without any extra alterations to the project setup.

I created the project, created a file called file.js.coffee, and started the middleman server. Upon looking at localhost:4567/file.js, the file does not exist. However, localhost:4567/file.js.coffee does seem to still exist.

Am I missing an obvious step? I don't remember doing any extra work to enable CoffeeScript last time.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting it in the `source/javascripts` folder?